# firefox won't open zoom client anymore

Tags: firefox, zoom-meeting

I had the standard zoom client installed from apt - it was 5.8.0 and today zoom refused to run and forced me to upgrade. since I couldn't get an upgrade from apt, I installed the snap package instead and removed the version from apt. so now I have 5.13.0 and it works fine as the client app, but firefox won't open it anymore. I get this app dialog I'veh I've not met before. How do I resolve this?

[image: my screenshot of the error dialog]

Comment: Snap apps at the moment does not have full support when interacting with `apt` apps.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, install the latest `.deb` version of Zoom from [here](https://zoom.us/client/latest/zoom_amd64.deb), and replace the snap version of Firefox with an APT version ([this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401) answer describes how to).

Then, Firefox and Zoom should be able to communicate with each other.