# Firefox unable to open zoom links on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, firefox, zoom-meeting

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 64-bit, and I cannot figure out for the life of me how to get Firefox (version 111.0.1 through the Firefox PPA not through Snap) to open Zoom links through the Zoom app (version 5.14.0 (1720), installed using the .deb file obtained from the official Zoom website). Every time I click on a Zoom link the dialog box opens asking me if I would like to open Zoom links using the Zoom app, I click open link and "remember my decision" and nothing happens. The Zoom app itself does not register any changes.

This seems like a common issue see: [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/wqmf6r/firefox_on_ubuntu_2204_wont_open_external_apps/), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410174/how-to-open-zoom-meeting-link-in-firefox-in-ubuntu-22-04), and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1451980/firefox-wont-open-zoom-client-anymore).

I tried different versions of Firefox and of the Zoom client. That did not work. I tried using the snap versions of Firefox, that did not work. I tried using the snap versions of Zoom, but the snap versions did not even load so I could not test that out.

Anything anyone can recommend (or enlighten me as to this being a bug in Firefox, Zoom, or both that I cannot solve) would be helpful.

This seems to be a common issue, but none of the previously mentioned fixes have helped me in resolving this issue.

Comment: This looks like you would be better to ask the Zoom people as it i their software you are having an issue with.

Comment: @David yeah i thought to ask here because other people who had similar issues also asked here. I don't suppose there is an "Ask Firefox" or "Ask Zoom" forum :D

Comment: Both Zoom and Firefox have their own support forums.

Comment: @David can you link them here? Or is it easy to just google them?

Comment: I'll also note that I was able to get this working when I used the Chromium web browser. It would seem the issue is with Firefox then.